# sqlFile refactoring in liquibase can't find file on the classpath

Tags: liquibase

The documentation for the `<sqlFile>` custom refactoring tag says that the classpath will be searched for the file. 
However I cannot get it to find my file, despite it being in the classpath.

The changeset element is:

```
<changeSet author="rebecca" id="9.1 - LoanIQ GoLive">
 <comment>No rollback script exists</comment>
 <sqlFile path="v9.1-loaniqgolive.sql"/>
</changeSet>
```

The ant task is:

```
<updateDatabase
    changeLogFile="@{changelog}"
    driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://${database.host}:${database.port};databaseName=${database.name}"
    username="${database.user}"
    password="${database.password}"
    promptOnNonLocalDatabase="false"
    dropFirst="false"
    classpathref="liquibase.path"/>
```

The build reports that the liquibase path is:

```
[echo] The liquibase path = D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Deploy GMM\workspace\app\build\database;D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Deploy GMM\workspace\app\build\tools\liquibase\liquibase.jar;D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Deploy GMM\workspace\app\build\lib\sqljdbc.jar
```

I have confirmed that v9.1-loaniqgolive.sql is definitely in the path (1st element).

Yet I get this error:

```
D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Deploy GMM\workspace\app\build\ant\functions\db.xml:56: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Invalid Migration File: <sqlfile path=v9.1-loaniqgolive.sql> -Unable to read file
at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parse(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:132)
```

My config looks OK, but it doesn't work. How can I solve this or debug further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick suggestion I have is to run Ant with -verbose and -debug command line parameters.  This puts out a lot of logging but generally helps get you closer to the source of the problem.

I will try to create an equivalent Ant task against one of my dbs and respond with any updates.

Comment: Thanks @mikemil. I tried to recreate the issue today and I couldn't! It worked without any problem. I had suspected spaces in the path.